All external connections and power queries are failing after running my python script which adds new rows into a separate table in my excel
My script I'm running in python is below. The script pulls all orders from a shopify store and adds them into a table in my excel. The script is working correctly however after running it and opening back my excel I get an error stating, "We found a problem with some content in 'Analytics.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust this workbook, click Yes.".
I click yes and each time it then deletes all my power queries and any external connections in my excel. My power queries do not have any reference to the table I am adding rows to through my script. If I make a copy of the excel and delete my power queries and external connections first I do not get any error either.
I'm running out of ideas and do not know why it keeps breaking the connections. Any help is appreciated.


import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
import sys
from time import sleep
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Shopify API credentials and initial URL
SHOP_NAME = 'xyz'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'token'
BASE_URL = f"https://{SHOP_NAME}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/orders.json"

headers = {
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

def fetch_orders_since(last_date):
    orders = []
    url = BASE_URL + f"?status=any&limit=250&created_at_min={last_date}"

    while url:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        orders.extend(data['orders'])
        link_header = response.headers.get('link')

        next_url = None
        if link_header:
            links = link_header.split(',')
            for link in links:
                if 'rel="next"' in link:
                    next_url = link.split(';')[0].strip()[1:-1]
                    break

        url = next_url

    return orders

def fetch_metafields(order_id):
    metafields_url = f"https://{SHOP_NAME}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/orders/{order_id}/metafields.json"
    response = requests.get(metafields_url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json().get('metafields', [])

def add_metafields_to_orders(orders):
    for order in orders:
        order_id = order['id']
        metafields = fetch_metafields(order_id)
        order['metafields'] = metafields
        sleep(0.5)
    return orders

def convert_type(value, target_type):
    if target_type == 'str':
        return str(value)
    elif target_type == 'int':
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            return 0
    elif target_type == 'float':
        try:
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            return 0.0
    elif target_type == 'bool':
        return bool(value)
    elif target_type == 'datetime':
        return pd.to_datetime(value, errors='coerce')
    else:
        return value

def get_column_types(ws, table):
    column_types = []
    table_range = table.ref
    start_cell, end_cell = table_range.split(':')
    start_row = ws[start_cell].row

    headers = [cell.value for cell in ws[start_row]]
    for column_name in headers:
        column_letter = ws[start_row][headers.index(column_name)].column_letter
        cell_value = ws[f"{column_letter}{start_row + 1}"].value  # Assuming data starts from the row below headers
        column_types.append(type(cell_value).__name__)
    return column_types

def append_orders_to_excel(orders, file_path, sheet_name='Shopify Orders', table_name='orders'):
    df = pd.json_normalize(orders)
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]

    table = ws.tables.get(table_name)

    if table is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Table {table_name} not found in sheet {sheet_name}")

    column_types = get_column_types(ws, table)

    if not df.empty:
        for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
            converted_row = [convert_type(value, column_types[idx]) for idx, value in enumerate(r)]
            ws.append(converted_row)

    # Update the table range to include new rows
    start_cell = table.ref.split(':')[0]
    end_cell = f"{get_column_letter(ws.max_column)}{ws.max_row}"
    table.ref = f"{start_cell}:{end_cell}"

    wb.save(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    last_date = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '2024-05-26T04:00:00'
    file_path = r'C:\path\to\Analytics.xlsx'

    orders = fetch_orders_since(last_date)
    orders_with_metafields = add_metafields_to_orders(orders)
    append_orders_to_excel(orders_with_metafields, file_path)
    print("Orders have been successfully appended to the Excel file")




Data connections are currently not supported in Openpyxl though work for this is ongoing. However, I suspect that supporting add-ins like Power Query is going to remain out of scope.

Does the Shopify data need to be in the same workbook as the queries?  I would probably separate them into two workbooks. If you need the Shopify data in the query workbook, I would pull that in using a query connected to the Shopify workbook.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
